# PHP: How to check if file not exists or permission is denied?

Tags: php, permissions, filesystems

I want to check if file do not exists. When `file_exists()` function returns `false` I can't be sure if the file do not exist or I don't have permission to the file.

How to discern that two possibilities?

Comment: If it because directory where the file resides is not readable or is it only the file itself. if it is the directory, then it is impossible to find out by design. The only way would be to make a check under a user that does have access, but that would have security implications.

Comment: Why do you want to check this anyways? What do you need it for?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`is_readable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) is what you want?

Comment: No, it is not. Because `is_readable` chcecks if file exists and is readable. I can check if the upper directory is readable, but there is the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could first try file_exists().  In the event that fails, you could try fopen() with the +a flag.  If that fails, you don't have permission.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check if file do not exists. When `file_exists()` function returns `false` I can't be sure if the file do not exist or I don't have permission to the file.

No, you must have understood something wrong. `file_exists()` will return `TRUE` if the file exists and `FALSE` if not. That has nothing to do with permissions of that file.

E.g. a file of which my script does not have permissions to read will make `file_exists` return `TRUE` because it exists.

However if I test with `is_readable` on that file, it will return `FALSE`. I don't have permissions to read the file.

Example:

```
$file = 'unreadable';
var_dump(file_exists($file), is_readable($file));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

**Edit:** Naturally, this is bound to the underlying system-libraries that PHP makes use of to obtain the information for file existence and file permissions. If PHP is not allowed to obtain the status about whether a file exists or not, it will tell you that the file does not exists. That's for example the case if you've got a directory which exists, but is not readable to the user:

```
$dir = 'unreadable';
$file = $dir.'/unreadable.ext';

var_dump(file_exists($dir), is_readable($dir));
# bool(true)
# bool(false)

var_dump(file_exists($file), is_readable($file));
# bool(false)
# bool(false)
```

As you would like to obtain the existence status of `$file`, the underlying permissions don't allow you to obtain it. Therefore the file does not exist for you. That's equally correct and you should be more precise what you actually need to find out. Because for you, the file does not exists. That's how directory permissions work (all examples are run on windows here, but these things are that common, that you have it in every common file-system implementation).

I hope that sheds some light into your issue.

Comment: Try that with this example:
You have path 1/2/3. File 3 exists, but PHP don't have permission to read directory 1/2. So file_exist('1/2/3') returns false, but the file exists in filesystem.

Comment: I'd say that if you don't have permission to read the directory, then the file does not exist. To you. That's kind of the point with directory permissions...

Comment: @pablo: That's not what you have asked for specifically - And what you say is how a file-system works. Maybe you need to read about file-systems first because PHP =/= Godmode - the file-system functions (if you don't use a stream wrapper of your own) are compiled against the libraries of your OS. What you can't do with your OS (Operating System) you can't do with PHP. Maybe that sheds some light to your issue, not that you look in the wrong place (e.g. PHP).

Comment: @Svish: Sure, otherwise the permissions of the file-system would be useless ;)

Comment: @Hakre Exactly :) Sorry, that was a response to pablo, not against your answer, if that wasn't clear :)

Comment: @Swish: I only wanted to underline what you wrote ;)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote function which check if file can exists. It return false if there is no such file in filesystem, otherwise it returns true. My function checks (bottom-up) directory structure. One should be fairly sure that `$root` directory exists.

```
private function fileCanExists($root, $path) {
    $root .= '/';
    if (file_exists($root . $path))
        return true;
    while ($path != '.') {
        $path = dirname($path);
        if (file_exists($root . $path)) {
            if (is_readable($root . $path))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

That is what mean when I wrote:

> I want to check if file do not exists.

Answer (score 0):

Check with `is_readable` and if return false, check with `file_exists`