# PHP Error on "Warning: printer_draw_bmp(): Failed to load bitmap"

Tags: php, printing, php-printer

I cannot print an image file using printer_draw_bmp() function. I already installed the php printer dll and imagick on the windows 7 (32 bits).

Here is my sample code. But I get "Warning: printer_draw_bmp(): Failed to load bitmap". Can anyone guide me to debug this?

```
<?php
$handle = printer_open();
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
printer_start_doc($handle, "My Doc");
printer_start_page($handle);

$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage("c:\\picStorage\\pic\\999-0001.jpg");
$image->setImageFormat("bmp");
$image->writeImage("C:\\test.bmp");

printer_draw_bmp($handle,"C:\\test.bmp", 300,600);

printer_end_page($handle);
printer_end_doc($handle);

printer_close($handle);
```

After I run the sample code, it will create a BMP image at C: directory.

[The BMP image at C: directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zDY9.png)

Comment: Are you sure `"C:\\test.bmp"` exists?

Comment: Yes, I can open the test.bmp at the C: directory.

Comment: Does PHP have permission to access the file?

Comment: How to check wether PHP have the permission to read the file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9649791/2020002 use that to verify that php can read the file

Comment: Ok, Thank you! I will test it now.

Comment: I wrote this. $file = "C:\\test.bmp"; var_dump(file_exists($file), is_readable($file));   It's output are " bool(true)bool(true)"

Comment: Is this mean I have the permission to read?

Comment: Yes, that means PHP can both see and read the file, so it might be the extension itself. Did you restart PHP after adding in the PECL extension?

Comment: I only restart the apache service. I think I try restart the PC now.

Comment: I tried restart the PC. Then restart the apache service again. The problem still persist. Weird. And I edit my code only load the C:\\test.bmp, don't have use the imagick convert the file format.

Comment: I wish I could help further, but the documentation for the extension you're trying to use doesn't have an English version

Comment: Can you send me the documentation link? Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing! http://php.net/manual/fa/book.printer.php

Comment: I found this documentation too. Haha.. Anyways, thanks for you help! I will test the code at another PC or put the printer name into the code.

Comment: You could also check to see if the extension is loaded by using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` is a blank PHP file

Comment: Ok, the printer  **Version 0.1.0-dev** ;
**Default printing device Brother HL-2240 series**;
**Module state working**;
**RCS Version $Id$**